# Subjective use of believe

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood

I said: "I believe he know me." But that was marked wrong. The right answer should be: "I believe he knows me." But if I remember correctly about subjunctive structure, after verbs like hope, believe, we should use the infinitive form of the verb? Like; "I hope he win" instead of "I hope he wins". Can someone confirm that for me?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30109/discussion-on-question-by-jxhyc-subjective-use-of-believe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of *believe, hope*, or *wish* takes the present subjunctive in English. (Although *wish* takes the past subjunctive in constructions like *I wish he were*...) Currently, the present subjunctive is used for requests and demands (neither of which *hope, believe,* or *wish* is, although *wish* comes fairly close), and while it is widespread in American English, many speakers of British English never or rarely use it. For example:

> I recommend that he *study* harder.

In the 19th century and earlier, the present subjunctive *was* used for hopes and wishes, and some frozen idioms persist from that time:

> Long *live* the king.

The use of the past subjunctive in English is quite different, and it might help to think of them as two completely different pieces of grammar.

Comment: "wish" takes the subjunctive all the time. "I wish I were taller." is very common. With "believe" it can be done in certain hypothetical or conditional phrasings such as "If I believed that it were so, then I would have ..."

Comment: @Zorf:  You're right. I was thinking about the present subjunctive, and not the past subjunctive. It's fixed now.

Comment: @Zorf Your claim _"wish" takes the subjunctive all the time_ is (taking the temporal in its precise sense) far from true according to these [GoogleNgrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+wish+I+was+taller%2CI+wish+I+were+taller&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20wish%20I%20was%20taller%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20wish%20I%20were%20taller%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CI%20wish%20I%20was%20taller%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20wish%20I%20were%20taller%3B%2Cc0). The modal preterite  'I wish I was taller' seems likely to outmode irrealis 'I wish I were taller'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "all the time" was an idiom in this case, I guess; replace it with "it's very common to do so. That the subjunctive in English is being replaced by other forms more and more is no secret.

Comment: @Zorf: Right: by *all the time*, I didn't literally mean *all the time*.